# Не выполняется скрипт

Tags: python-3.x

Я не знаю что с ним просиходит, но дела плохи.

```
number = int(input("Введите \033[01;38;05;34mчисло\033[0m\n>>>"))

for item in range(number+1, 2):
    if number%item==0:
        print("÷\033[01;38;05;157m{item}\o33[0m: \033[01;38;05;34m" + "v\033[0m")
    else:
        print("÷\033[01;38;05;157m{item}\o33[0m: \033[01;38;05;196m" + "x\033[0m")
```

От этого простого скрипта сходят с ума все компилеры, а pydroid и вовсе пишет ерунду. Помогите пожалуйста, что это и как это решить.

Comment: Что значит «сходят с ума», какую «ерунду»? Цикл for ни разу не выполняется, потому что range здесь пустой

Comment: `range(number+1, 2)` -> `range(2, number+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

- Во первых, у вас какой-то странный цикл `for`
- Во вторых, вы забыли добавить `f` перед строкой, поэтому у вас просто выведется `{item}`
- В третьих, вместо `\033`, вы написали `\o33`